# MongoDB: Query documents where one of its field is equal to one of its sub-document field?

Tags: database, mongodb

Given the following dataset of books with a related books list:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "related_books" : [ { book_id: 1 }, { book_id: 2 }, { book_id: 3 } ] } <-- this one
{ "_id" : 2, "related_books" : [ { book_id: 1 } }
{ "_id" : 3, "related_books" : [ { book_id: 3 }, { book_id: 2 } ] } <-- and this one
{ "_id" : 4, "related_books" : [ { book_id: 1 }, { book_id: 2 } ] }
```

I'm trying to get the list of books when _id === related_book.book_id, so in this case:
book 1: it contains a related_book with book_id = 1
book 3: it contains a related_book with book_id = 3

I've been trying to find my way with aggregate filters but I can't make it work with the check of a sub-document field:

```
db.books.aggregate([{  
    "$project": {
      "selected_books": {
        "$filter": {
          "input": "$books", 
          "as":"book", 
          "cond": { "$in": ["$_id", "$$book.related_books.book_id" ]
    }}}}}])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is my solution to this problem:

```
db.getCollection("books").aggregate([{
    $addFields: {
        hasBookWithSameId: {
            $reduce: {
                input: "$related_books",
                initialValue: false,
                in: {$or: ["$$value", {$eq: ["$_id", "$$this.book_id"]}]}
            }
        }
    }
},
{
    $match: {
        hasBookWithSameId: true
    }
}])
```

In the first step I'm creating a field hasBookWithSameId that represents a boolean: true if there is a related book with same id, false otherwise. This is made using the [reduce](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/reduce/) operator, which is a powerful tool for dealing with embedded arrays, it works by iterating over the array verifying if it has any related book with the same id as the parent.

At the end, I just match all the documents that have this property set to true.

**Update:**
There is a more elegant solution to this problem with just one aggregation step, using $map and $anyElementTrue

```
db.collection.aggregate({
    $match: {
        $expr: {
            $anyElementTrue: {
                $map: {
                    input: "$related_books",
                    in: {
                        $eq: ["$$this.book_id", "$_id"]
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
})
```